# Find the angle bisectors of a triangle with side $a$ and adjacent angles $\beta$ and $\gamma$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Find the angle bisectors of a triangle with side $a$ and adjacent angles $\beta$ and $\gamma$.
[image]
I am trying to solve the problem using the law of sines, because we have just studied it, but I can't seem to find a solution. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi! Do you want to compute $\ell_a$?

Comment: Hi! I want to compute the angle bisectors of the triangle, including $l_a.$ I have constructed it in the diagram, because I think that the others will be found in a similar way. Isn't that right?

Comment: Hint: Remember that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=180^\circ$. Use sine theorem to calculate $AC=b$ and $AB=c$. Then, notice that $\angle ADC=\frac{\alpha}{2}+\beta, \angle ADB=\frac{\alpha}{2}+\gamma$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop, thank you for the response. Can I ask you for which triangle should I use the sine theorem?

Comment: First to $\triangle ABC$ to find $b, c$, then to $\triangle ADC$ (or $\triangle ADB$) to find $l_a$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop, so I got that $b=\dfrac{a\sin\beta}{\sin\alpha}$ and $c=\dfrac{a\sin\gamma}{\sin\alpha}$.

Comment: Correct, and note $\sin\alpha = \sin(180^\circ-\beta-\gamma)=\sin(\beta + \gamma)$, for what it's worth. Now let's jump onto $\triangle ADC$: you have two angles and $b$ ...

Comment: @StinkingBishop thank you for the help! So, we will have $\dfrac{AD}{AC} = \dfrac{\sin\gamma}{\sin\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{2}+\beta\right)}$. How can I write $\dfrac{\alpha}{2}+\beta$ with $\beta$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop, I am sorry if my question wasn't clear. Do you need me to clarify? Thank you in advfance!

Comment: It is fine, $\alpha=180^\circ-\beta-\gamma$ so $\frac{\alpha}{2}+\beta=90^\circ+\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}$ and $\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}+\beta\right)=\sin\left(90^\circ+\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\right)$ ... I guess...

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @StinkingBishop, can I ask you something more? I want to simplify $\sin\left(\alpha+\dfrac{\beta}{2}\right).$ I get that it is equal to $\sin\left(\dfrac{\beta}{2}+\gamma\right)$. Is that right and should I leave the answer this way or write it as $\sin\left(\dfrac{\beta+2\gamma}{2}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Another way using areas :

$$[\triangle ABD] + [\triangle ADC] = [\triangle ABC]$$

In the usual notation, $BC=a, CA=b, AB=c$,

$$\frac{1}{2}c l_a \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} + \frac{1}{2}b l_a \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} = \frac{1}{2}b c \sin \alpha$$
$$\Rightarrow l_a=\frac{bc}{b+c}\frac{\sin \alpha}{\sin (\alpha/2)}$$
$$\therefore \boxed{l_a=\frac{2bc}{b+c}\cos (\alpha/2)}$$

Similar formulae for $l_b$, $l_c$.

Comment: Maybe your answer should include how b and c can be found becuase  they are not given.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: find b and c by sine rule, then use following formula:

$$tan \frac{\gamma}2=\sqrt {\frac{(p-a)(p-b)}{p(p-c)}}$$

Where $p=\frac{a+b+c}2$